# Missing required parameters for [Route] unit testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have this piece of code for feature test for controller store method

```
$response= $this->post(route('contact.store'),[$client->value])
```

but I got this error

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: contact.store] [URI: client/{clientValue}/contact].
```

How  I can fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

When posting to an url with an argument e.g. `/posts/1` you need to give the route helper the necessary data.

With this example `route('post.show', ['id' => 1])`